# How to access gallery -> Camera Media videos and display it in List on button Click?

Tags: android, list, video, image

i am beginner in Android app development i am working on a app which lists the videos and images  and uploads them from android phone to the windows server,

Button Listvideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Listvideo);
        Listvideo.setOnClickListener(this);

help me out  with the listing images and videos........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within your OnClick method:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

onActivityResult method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri photoUri = intent.getData();

        if (photoUri != null) {
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this
                    .getContentResolver(), photoUri);
                your_imgv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                profilePicPath = photoUri.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does one capture the image that the user selected to use elsewhere in the app?